# Listview is gone

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi I am using Ribbon Menu library to show a sliding menu in my app

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

and here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/abs__textfield_search_default_holo_dark"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/abs__ic_search"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:textColorHint="#7F462C" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
    <com.darvds.ribbonmenu.RibbonMenuView
        android:id="@+id/ribbonMenuView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my problem here is that my list view is gone i mean i just can see the Ribbon Menu and the edit text so any help?

Comment: ListView's height is wrap_content. Are you sure you added data to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `include layout` hidding your listview

```
<com.darvds.ribbonmenu.RibbonMenuView
        android:id="@+id/ribbonMenuView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

set wrap_content or set the size to the layout_height to some value like "100dp"

Comment: you mean RibbonMenuView?